# why map points are not displaying in mapKitView?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

Here i trying to display multiplier places in MKMapView,But it's not showing

```
import MapKit

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

 let locations = [
    ["title": "New York, NY",    "latitude": 40.713054, "longitude": -74.007228],
    ["title": "Los Angeles, CA", "latitude": 34.052238, "longitude": -118.243344],
    ["title": "Chicago, IL",     "latitude": 41.883229, "longitude": -87.632398]
]


 override func viewDidLoad()
{
for location in locations {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = location["title"] as? String
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: location["longitude"] as! Double)
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
}
```

my map is displaying default India map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoom

```
 mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
 mapView.showAnnotations(mapview.annotations,animated:true)
```

BTW think of a model instead

```
struct Item {
  let title:String
  let latitude,longitude:Double
}
```

Comment: tq @Sh_Khan i am facing another problem, zooming to all locations is not working.can u tell me solution.